# Using GHC api to rewrite program

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'm trying to write a piece of code that does the following

1. Take as input a Haskell module
2. Parse and type check the input module
3. Find all expressions in the module that have type IO a
4. Add a function of type IO a -> IO a to each of these expressions
5. Compile and run the rewritten module

I've been digging around the GHC api to help do this but its fairly impenetrable for someone new to serious Haskell development. I tried reading the [GHC as a library wiki page](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/As_a_library) but many decisions they make (e.g. their choice of DynFlags) aren't clarified. Any tips or places to look would be super helpful!

Comment: could you explain a bit more of what you are trying to achieve - maybe the task you have can be done with other means - be it `Generics` or `TemplateHaskell` right now I find it rather difficult to write a meaningful answer. Also be aware that recommendation of libraries/blogs and so forth is not what SO.com is for, you are better of writing to the mailing list or ask on reddit.

Comment: Basically I'm trying to get every expression of type IO a, add a function of type IO a -> IO a to each of these expressions, and run the resulting code

Comment: i think you can extract module information with template haskell https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell - and manipulate the functions in said module - though I don't know whether you can filter based on the type of that function.

Comment: @BenPerez, do you mind saying *why* you want to apply this `IO a -> IO a` function? What function do you have in mind?  Again, maybe there is another way to do what you want.

Comment: @luqui its basically for getting better stack traces than possible with existing tools. I want to be able to feed this IO a -> IO a function various pieces of info and have it log them. So the point of this whole thing is being able to run a program in a customizable debugging mode, which essentially rewrites the program to have these trace functions peppered throughout.

Comment: Why bother with the `IO` bit?  Since its a debugging tool, you could go with `Debug.Trace`-style annotations (or something else using `unsafePerformIO`). And then you wouldn't need to know the type, so you could do it in TH just by traversing the syntax.